# Named native query mapping in orm.xml

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am very new to Hibernate. I am trying to externalize basic SQL query to orm.xml

My query

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  FROM DUAL
```

I have tried following :

```
<named-native-query 
    name="JobTrackerEntity.getCurrentTimestamp"
    result-class="java.sql.Timestamp">
    <query>
        SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  FROM DUAL
    </query>
</named-native-query>
```

But I get following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.sql.Timestamp
```

Please let me know how can I write the query in orm.xml. Also if I can refer any resources to get better understanding.

---

Update:

I have added a method in repository interface as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface TrackerRepository extends JpaRepository<TrackerEntity, TrackerId> {

    @Query(nativeQuery=true)
    Timestamp getCurrentTimestamp();
}
```

I'm calling `getCurrentTimestamp()` to execute query.

Comment: How do you execute the query? Please show some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove `result-class="java.sql.Timestamp"` because the result-class property must be an Entity.

**edit:**

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` results in a missing mapping in Hibernate dialect. You must provide your own dialect or if you don't need the timezone you better use:

```
SELECT LOCALTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL
```

Comment: `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2014; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2014` : This is the exception I get if I remove `result-class="java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: You are using Oracle DB?

Comment: In-mem H2 database.

Comment: The problem is that the type 2014 (TimestampWithTimezone) is not registered with the H2Dialect of Hibernate. I will see I finde something

Comment: I updated my answer. Do you really need the timezone?